# Merge 2 files from starter and spring-boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, yaml

in my project i have starter and spring-boot application with this starter.

Starter contains application.yaml file with few properties.
For example:

```
my:
  test:
    value: test

spring:
  profiles:
    active: development
```

i'm adding application.yaml file to my spring-boot app, and values from starter's yaml aren't injected to context.
My question, 
how i can configure 2 yaml files in starter and application with option for override values with spring-boot app's starter, for example:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: testing
```

After merge i want to have:

spring.profiles.active=testing
my.test.value=test

Currently it's failed with error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'my.test.value' in value "${my.test.value}"

Comment: Did you read this? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `spring.profiles.include`

```
spring:
  profiles:
   active: testing
   include: default
```

Or you can create different `application-profile.yml` (for example application-testing.yml) and specify the profile while starting spring boot application

**Command**

```
java -jar name.jar spring.profiles.active=testing // it will pick the properties values from application-testing.yml
```

In the yml file use include to include any other profiles

**application-testing.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: default
```

Comment: thanks, it's resolved allmost all my problems, one thing if add to spring-boot's yaml         


my:
  test:
    value: spring-boot test value


In app value is test from starter.

Comment: sorry i did not get that comment, please accept it if it solved your problem @Ridov

Answer (score 0):

@Deadpool
One issue with override
I made application-starter.yaml in starter and include it in sprinng-boot with include.

```
my:
  test:
    value: spring--123


spring:
  profiles:
    active: development
    include: starter
```

I injected with @Value

```
@Value("${my.test.value}")
private String testval;
```

and testval=test (from starter) Have i option for make values from application.yaml more primary?

thanks

Comment: yep, thanks a lot, it's fantastic approach 
problem with override only, how to solve it?

Comment: what was the issue? i said i showed this approach in my answer and i don't know about issue you are having